# jQuery - if mobile device redirect then if click the link ignore the first if

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, execute

I use this code to redirect user that using mobile/tablet device to mobile version
but i want when they click "Go To full version" then ignore the first if.
currently when user click that link, they redirect again to mobile version.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location.href = "http://m.website.com";
}

if($('#ClickFull').click(function()){
// i don't know what can ignore the above if.
}
```

i guess i should put my code in a function, if i'm in right, how?

Comment: Set a cookie. Read the cookie within the `if` statement. If the cookie isn't set to whatever the value for displaying the full page is, execute the `window.location.href`, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: You can set cookie when they click fullsite and you can check that cookie in 1st if. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Set a cookie. Read the cookie within the `if` statement. If the cookie isn't set to whatever the value for displaying the full page is, execute the `window.location.href`, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Simply append a query string to the url, such as ?m=false when someone clicks on the full version link and then add that to your condition for mobile devices check, such as if( /Android|webOS|iP.... && !location.search.match(/m=false/gi) ) { ... }

Comment: A redirect based on the user agent is a terrible thing. Use a "javascript media query" to check for the abilities of the browser instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist information about user preference between page reloads. One way is to use cookie. But I find WebStorage more convenient to use. In your case `sessionStorage` would be ideal. Something like this:

```
if (!sessionStorage.fullVersion && /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.href = "http://m.website.com";
}

$('#ClickFull').click(function() {
    sessionStorage.fullVersion = true;
});
```

`sessionStorage` will be cleared once the session is ended, e.g. browser tab is closed. If you need to remember user's choice longer use `localStorage` instead.

Comment: I used this method , but didn't work. they redirect again to mobile version. a question: i should use this code to full version or mobile version or both? @dfsq